# Gitlab pipeline stuck at pending state Gitlab runner not assigned

Tags: gitlab

I have registered gitlab-runner with the following command

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
    --registration-token "########" \
    --executor "docker+machine" \
    --docker-image "docker:stable"\
    --description "docker-runner" \
    --run-untagged="true" \
    --locked="false" \
    --access-level="not_protected"
```

Then run `sudo gitlab-runner verify` here is the result:

```
sudo gitlab-runner verify
Runtime platform            arch=amd64 os=linux pid=7162 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Running in system-mode.
                                                   
Verifying runner... is alive    runner=pD2Prt75
```

At the project level, I see the following image (1)

[image]

At the Group-level, I see the following image (2)

[image]

**Problem**: When I trigger a pipeline it gets stuck in a pending state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `docker` executor instead of `docker+machine` since docker machine was deprecated by docker https://docs.docker.com/machine/

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
    --registration-token "########" \
    --executor "docker" \
    --docker-image "docker:stable"\
    --description "docker-runner" \
    --run-untagged="true" \
    --locked="false" \
    --access-level="not_protected"
```